# The meaning of constructor in data constructor and Type constructor in Haskell

Tags: haskell, constructor

I am going through Hudak's "Gentle introduction to Haskell". As stated in my earlier questions, I have a little experience with C and C++. So when I came across the term "Constructors" in the introduction to type constructors and data constructors I can't help but wonder if any similarities are there with C++ constructors or is it completely analogous with the later.

So, the first example that Hudak provides is the following:

```
data Color  = Red|Green|Blue
```

So from the first example I got to know that the RHS is the data constructor. However, here I wasn't clear about type constructors.

In the next example:

```
data Point a = Pt a a
```

It has been clearly stated that `Point` is the data constructor and `Pt` is the type constructor. So what exactly does a constructor do? Is it a function call as it is in case of C++?

How exactly are the work of point and pt differentiated? what is "pt" doing?

Comment: You've got it the wrong way round: `Point` is the type constructor and `Pt` is the data constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting a bit bogged down in terminology. I'd probably say "`Point` is a higher-kinded type" instead. That just means that it forms a new type given another type. Usually we just refer to `Pt` as a constructor.
Here's an example:

```
data Point a = Pt a a

samplePoint :: Point Int
samplePoint = Pt 1 2
```

Comment: Correct, however something like `Point` is indeed commonly called _type constructor_. You may have a point (pun not intended) in that this terminology doesn't make a lot of sense, but it is standard.

Comment: Note that "higher order" is used for functions taking functions, e.g. `(T->T)->...`. Similarly, "higher kind" refers to types which have a "constructor" argument e.g. `data T f a = K (f a)` where `T :: (*->*)->*`. I would say that `Point`, on its own, is not higher kinded.

Comment: Agreed. `Point` simply has a *different* kind (`* -> *`) than  `Color` (`*`).

Answer (score 1):

A constructor can indeed be used to, well, *construct a value* (or type, respectively), like a C++ class constructor can:

```
Prelude> data Point a = Pt a a
Prelude> :type Pt
Pt :: a -> a -> Point a
Prelude> :kind Point
Point :: * -> *
```

This corresponds, roughly, to

```cpp
template <typename A>
struct Point {
  A x, y;
  Point(A x, A y): x(x), y(y) {}
};
```

...or, to get the same name,

```cpp
template <typename A>
Point Pt(A x, A y) { return Point(x,y); }
```

But that's not all, a value constructor can also be used to *deconstruct* a value:

```
centerDist :: Floating a => Point a -> a
centerDist (Pt x y) = sqrt $ x^2 + y^2
```

There's nothing really analogous in C++ because that doesn't have pattern matching.